# c++ odeint - integrate a static ode

Tags: c++, function, templates, boost, static

I have trouble with my c++ program and not good enough in C++... Would you please help me with this ?

So I use boost::odeint. I've got my ode and the integration function, coming from the library, in a class C. But I've got the error that "ode" has to be non-static (error: reference to non-static member function must be called). Even if integrate and the ode are in the same class.

How can I do to make my integration function uses a static ode ?

Thank you in advance !

```
class C
{
public :
typedef boost::array< double , 3 > state_type;
C(const state_type &B);
~C();

const void ode( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , double t);
void write_out( const state_type &x , const double t );
void integration();

private :
const state_type x;
};

void C :: ode(const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , double t)
{ (...) }

void C :: integration()
{
    out.open( "results.txt" );
    integrate_const( runge_kutta_fehlberg78< state_type >() , ode,
                    x , 0.0 , 10.0 , 0.01, write_out );
    out.close();
}

## Main.cpp

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

C::state_type x = {{ 10.0 , 10.0 , 10.0 }};
C Com1 (x);

Com1.integration();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use dollar signs in your identifiers.

Comment: move the const to the end of the ode function: void ode( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , double t) const;

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do here: const void :: ode(const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , double t ) - this is not valid C++ syntax

Comment: What the heck `const void` return specification should do? Besides that `const void :: ode(...)` should be `void C::ode(...)` for the definition of a class member function.

Comment: @cppguy: Are you sure?  I think `const void` may be allowed (though useless outside of TMP), and the declaration declares a function `ode` in the global namespace.  I think it is valid C++ syntax (though not what he intended)

Comment: Sorry for the dollar, it was suppose to be a "&".
I'm sorry I'm new in C++... I change the code from boost::odeint examples "lorrenz" to be in class, but it's almost the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems:

First, remove the const in the definition of the x class member:

```
class C
{
    /* ... */
    state_type x;
}
```

Second, defining the ode in terms of a member function is possible but then you need to bind it to the current object. It is much easier to define ode via the bracket operator `operator()`. So replace ode with

```
void operator()( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , double t);
```

and call the ode via

```
integrate_const( runge_kutta_fehlberg78< state_type >() , boost::ref( *this ) ,
                x , 0.0 , 10.0 , 0.01, write_out );
```

Comment: Thank you this problem is solved ! Just need to overload to make it works...